# imshow opencv doens't show image

Tags: opencv

this is my code, when I try to use imshow the image is black

```
    cv::Mat src(height, width, CV_16U);
    for (int i = 0; i < width* height; ++i)
    {
        src.at<unsigned short>(i) = input_image[i]/1023;
    }
    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::resize(src, temp, cv::Size(), 0.3, 0.3, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
    cv::imshow("image1", temp);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    cv::Mat imageData;
    cv::cvtColor(src, imageData, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2RGB);

    cv::resize(imageData, temp, cv::Size(), 0.3, 0.3, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
    cv::imshow("image1", temp);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

if I change my code to

```
cv::Mat src(height, width, CV_32F);
for (int i = 0; i < width* height; ++i)
{
    src.at<float>(i) = input_image[i]/1023;
}
```

[image]

can you explain how to display the image?

Comment: I would *guess* because `input_image[i]/1023` yields a value between 0 and 1 and when you cast that to an unsigned short it's converted to 0. What is the type and range of values in `input_image`?

Comment: It is a double up to 1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `input_image` is in the range `0..1023`, by dividing by 1023 you're getting a value between 0 and 1. When you cast that to an unsigned integer type, your image is all zeros. (It might round some of them to 1, but that's not really going to be visible anyway.)

To get the number to use the full range of `unsigned short`, you need to multiply by `65535`:

```
src.at<unsigned short>(i) = input_image[i]/1024*65536;
```

or

```
src.at<unsigned short>(i) = input_image[i]*64;
```